# Using JavaScript in Divi/WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a small piece of JavaScript code that I want to put into my site made with the Divi theme. I made a child theme with a functions.php file and a js file. I put the following code in the functions.php file:

```
<?php
   function wpdivi_theme_name_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . 
  '/js/code.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
  }
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdivi_theme_name_scripts' );
?>
```

In divi I used the code module to set up the HTML. I tested the code in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EXNZr/1359/).

However when I use the same code on my WordPress site it doesn't work. I tried a simple alert box in js but that doesn't work either.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is working for our wordpress site which is used DIVI theme. Could you please check with js file path.

If you are using **"get_template_directory_uri()"** function, the file should be there in parent theme js folder.

If you are using **"get_stylesheet_directory_uri()"** function, the file should be there in child theme js folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the code module to enter the JavaScript directly. If you just surround your JS code in `<script>` tags inside the code module, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Or, just go to Divi Settings > Integrations > Add script.